# Android Studio doesn't record Robo Test

Tags: android-studio, flutter, firebase-test-lab

I've Android Studio (AS) 3.4.1. Trying to record a Robo Script for the UI for my Flutter project. Followed pretty much everything from Google's [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test). The recording only records phone's physical button press but not any tap on the screen. Example below.

I've tried both Android emulators and physical device. Both have got same problem. Tried by uninstalling and installing Firebase related plug-ins from AS including restarts in between.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Output of Robo Script]
(In the above screen-shot, taps between "Delay 7000 milliseconds" and "Press Back" wasn't recorded).

Comment: Robo scripts are meant for native Android UI, not Flutter.

Comment: Thanks. You just saved me a couple more hours in R&D figuring out what's wrong with my Android Studio set-up. I am not sure about SO's policy around it your I accept your answer. If you just post the above comment as answer then I'll mark the question as answered. Thanks mate.

Comment: This is not the same as robo scripts but you can record manual tests and rerun them with the `flutster` Flutter plugin on Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robo scripts are meant for native Android UI, not Flutter.

For automated testing on Flutter, please check https://flutter.dev/docs/testing.